# @nebular customise menu (NbMenuComponent) html not working

Tags: icons, angular8, nebular

I am using akveo/ngx-admin theme for my project. And i need to customise sidebar menu icons. nebular came with eva icons but i need fontawesome icons.

tried to change "/node_modules/@nebular/theme/components/menu/menu-item.component.html"
but html changes not reflecting

```
<span *ngIf="menuItem.group">
  <!-- <nb-icon class="menu-icon" [icon]="menuItem.icon" *ngIf="menuItem.icon"></nb-icon> -->
  <i class="{{menuItem.icon}}"></i>
  {{ menuItem.title }}
</span>
<a *ngIf="menuItem.link && !menuItem.url && !menuItem.children && !menuItem.group"
   [routerLink]="menuItem.link"
   [queryParams]="menuItem.queryParams"
   [fragment]="menuItem.fragment"
   [skipLocationChange]="menuItem.skipLocationChange"
   [attr.target]="menuItem.target"
   [attr.title]="menuItem.title"
   [class.active]="menuItem.selected"
   (mouseenter)="onHoverItem(menuItem)"
   (click)="onItemClick(menuItem);">
  <!-- <nb-icon class="menu-icon" [icon]="menuItem.icon" *ngIf="menuItem.icon"></nb-icon> -->
  <i class="{{menuItem.icon}}"></i>
  <span class="menu-title">{{ menuItem.title }}</span>
</a>
<a *ngIf="menuItem.url && !menuItem.children && !menuItem.link && !menuItem.group"
   [attr.href]="menuItem.url"
   [attr.target]="menuItem.target"
   [attr.title]="menuItem.title"
   [class.active]="menuItem.selected"
   (mouseenter)="onHoverItem(menuItem)"
   (click)="onSelectItem(menuItem)">
  <!-- <nb-icon class="menu-icon" [icon]="menuItem.icon" *ngIf="menuItem.icon"></nb-icon> -->
  <i class="{{menuItem.icon}}"></i>
  <span class="menu-title">{{ menuItem.title }}</span>
</a>
<a *ngIf="!menuItem.children && !menuItem.link && !menuItem.url && !menuItem.group"
   [attr.target]="menuItem.target"
   [attr.title]="menuItem.title"
   [class.active]="menuItem.selected"
   (mouseenter)="onHoverItem(menuItem)"
   (click)="$event.preventDefault(); onItemClick(menuItem);">
  <!-- <nb-icon class="menu-icon" [icon]="menuItem.icon" *ngIf="menuItem.icon"></nb-icon> -->
  <i class="{{menuItem.icon}}"></i>
  <span class="menu-title">{{ menuItem.title }}</span>
</a>
<a *ngIf="menuItem.children"
   (click)="$event.preventDefault(); onToggleSubMenu(menuItem);"
   [attr.target]="menuItem.target"
   [attr.title]="menuItem.title"
   [class.active]="menuItem.selected"
   (mouseenter)="onHoverItem(menuItem)"
   href="#">
  <!-- <nb-icon class="menu-icon" [icon]="menuItem.icon" *ngIf="menuItem.icon"></nb-icon> -->
  <i class="{{menuItem.icon}}"></i>
  <span class="menu-title">{{ menuItem.title }}</span>
  <nb-icon class="expand-state" [icon]="getExpandStateIcon()" pack="nebular-essentials"></nb-icon>
</a>
<ul *ngIf="menuItem.children"
    [class.collapsed]="!(menuItem.children && menuItem.expanded)"
    [class.expanded]="menuItem.expanded"
    [@toggle]="toggleState"
    class="menu-items">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of menuItem.children">
    <li nbMenuItem *ngIf="!item.hidden"
        [menuItem]="item"
        [class.menu-group]="item.group"
        (hoverItem)="onHoverItem($event)"
        (toggleSubMenu)="onToggleSubMenu($event)"
        (selectItem)="onSelectItem($event)"
        (itemClick)="onItemClick($event)"
        class="menu-item">
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

i have commented "nb-icon" and changed it with "i" tag to render fontawesome icon.

[image: error after changing menu icon to fontawesome]

[image: menu-item.component.html after changes (not reflecting)]

[image: pages-menu.ts (icon changes from eva to fontawesome)]

fontawesome free css is imported into angular.json and fontawesome icons are working properly in project. not sure what to do. anything would be helpful, thank you.

Comment: hi, anyone know about this ?

Answer (score 1):

try adding font awesome to libraries using `NbIconLibraries` service like

```
constructor {
 ...
 private icons: NbIconLibraries,
 ...
} {
 this.icons.registerFontPack(...)
 // or
 this.icons.registerSvgPack(...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can install awesome fonts in your project and add the below code to your parent module which is PagesModule in below example

```
export class PagesModule {
  constructor(iconsLibrary: NbIconLibraries){
    iconsLibrary.registerFontPack('fa', { packClass: 'fa', iconClassPrefix: 'fa' 
    });
  }
}
```